# sql query to find the substring present in a different table

Tags: sql

```
Table "sub":
----------------------
sub_ser   ----->column name
----------------------
a1
a2                      
a3
a4
----------------------




Table "zvm"
--------------------------
vms_ser          ->column name
------------------------
a1,a2,a3          

a1,a2

a1 

----------------------
```

let's say both tables have only one column..
Query needed: to fetch the column "sub_ser" from the table "sub" which contains independent entries for all the entries which are arranged in combinations as shown in table "zvm".

ex:
for the single entry "a1,a2,a3" in the table "zvm" we need to check whether each of the a1 and a2 and a3 are  INDIVIDUALLY/ INDEPENDENTLY present in the table "sub" 
Hope u got the question...

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct sub_ser
from sub
where sub_ser in (
select unnest(string_to_array(vms_ser, ',')) from zvm )
```

this will work well on PostgreSql Database

Answer (score 0):

I think you've to write a procedue to get it done. Take a look at http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,78776,148332 . Use a similar procedure specifying `,` as your delimitter to retrieve a1, a2 and a3 seperately and then make your query on table 1.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, select from "zvm" table and then select separately from "sub" table simply like this-

```
select distinct sub_ser
from sub
where sub_ser in ('a1','a2','a3')
```